# How to write timeout for firestore on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

When i updating a firestore data without a internet connection. it just stuck there. how do I timeout a firestore request. or what is the best way to do this?

```
try {
  await userRef.document(uid).updateData({ 
    "data": data 
  });
  return Response.isSuccess({});
} catch(err) {
  print(err);
  return Response.isError(err);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is timeout method in firestore.

```
 await userRef.document(uid).updateData({ 
    "data": data 
  }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 1));
```

Comment: is there a documentation for `timeout`? i can't find it

Answer (score 1):

Try using transactions, you can set a timeout duration.

```
await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) {

await tx.get / set / update 

}).timeout(Duration(seconds: 1), onTimeout: () {

print('Timed out');

});
```

Comment: is there a documentation for `timeout`? i can't find it